# Значки навигации в ActionBar

Tags: actionbar, android, java

Здравствуйте.

В моем приложении использую navigationDrawer, в actionBar слева иконка приложения, и "сендвич" (3 горизонтальные полоски). Когда из navigationDrawer`a перехожу в другую активити, то "сендвич" меняется на стрелку. Насколько помню, это [антипаттерн](http://habrahabr.ru/post/213097/), стрелка должна появляться, когда мы входим вглубь по навигации, а тут только 1-й уровень.

Как сделать, так, чтобы появлялась не стрелка, а оставался "сендвич"?

**UPD:** отображал фрагменты методами .add() и .replace(). Но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Вы фрагменты как открываете? Реплейсите текущий просто или добавляете в стек?

Comment: Вообще, я имел ввиду, что открываю новую активити из drawera, но это конечно, не принципиально. Но если понял нужно использовать .replace?

Comment: нет, это не антипаттерн, все логично. должна быть стрелка(!)

Comment: @Andreich в случае фрагментов тоже?

Comment: @Suvitruf обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Изменил открываемые страницы на фрагменты.

Добавляю их вот таким способом:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container_frame, fragment)
        .commit();
```

Теперь работает как надо

Answer (score 0):

а хотя стоп, я только осознал ваш случай, тут вы правы, но не совсем.
Если через DN вы открываете активити, то стрелка является нормальным явлением, а если фрагмент - то тут думать надо от содержимого фрагмента. Тут тонкий момент.

Comment: @Andreich так вот, допустим, я открываю новый фрагмент. И у меня появляется стрелка назад. Как сделать, чтобы был "сендвич"?

Comment: в новом фрагменте менять только

Answer (score 0):

При открытии фрагмента можно вызывать метод у `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, который отвечает за это:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(enable);
```

Если передаёте туда true, то будет сэндвич, если false, то стрелка.

Comment: Спасибо, взял на вооружение!